# Device Communication Servers for use with OpenGTS

Tags: java, mysql

I want to write 2 Device Communication Servers for use with OpenGTS (Enterprise).  Devices are Teltonika FM4200 and WirlessLinks Piccolo STX. can u give me a some tutorial or something useful.  I still don't have idea on it.

Comment: Show us what have you done up to now. Also, the tags and this question seem unrelevant...

Comment: i haven't no idea about OpenGTS .and how to done with java . and i don't know y it needed tomcat . and y set path for GTS_HOME. i am try project in eclipse  but isn't successes

Comment: It sounds to me you do not know anything? why don't spend some time to read [OpenGTS](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/), find the example code or documentation in OpenGTS and that should give you an idea why it needed tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of DCS you can use [Traccar](http://www.traccar.org/) server which already supports FM4200, the second device might already be supported as well, I just need some message examples to verify that. Configuration file to integrate two systems can be found [here](http://www.traccar.org/docs/opengts.jsp).